# Automatic syntax highlighting will not work in gVim

Tags: r, vim, syntax-highlighting

I think I've tried every intuitive combination of these four commands, with and without colons, in my _vimrc:

```
syntax enable
syntax on
set filetype=r
set syntax=r
```

But when I open a script in gVim, it's all one solid color. Within a session, both ':set syntax=r' and ':set filetype=r' work fine, while the other two do nothing.

My full _vimrc is below:

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin
set keymodel-=stopsel

set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let eq = ''
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
      let eq = '"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction

filetype plugin indent on
" show existing tab with 4 spaces width
set tabstop=4
" when indenting with '>', use 4 spaces width
set shiftwidth=4
" On pressing tab, insert 4 spaces
set expandtab

"show line numbers
set number

"syntax highlighting for R
"syntax enable
syntax on
set filetype=r
"set syntax=r
colorscheme elflord

"see commands as they're being typed
set showcmd

"change the key combo for normal mode to 'jk'
inoremap jk <ESC>

"add line below cursor in insert mode
:autocmd InsertEnter * set cul
:autocmd InsertLeave * set nocul
```

Comment: It looks fine to me. I'm suspicious that it works as intended when you manually set the syntax to r when the file is open, but not in your _vimrc file. Are you sure you're changing the proper _vimrc file (what location is that file)? Also, you are including both the vimrc_example.vim and mswin.vim files. Is there anything in those that could be causing the issue? I have those commented out myself and then point to my own custom vimrc file where I put all my configuration.

Comment: @JasonDown - My main _vimrc is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc`.  I know this file is working because gVim responds to other edits I make to it.  I commented the lines that source vimrc_example.vim and mswin.vim, but the problem persists.

Comment: Well, what if you try the following (instead of `set filetype=r`) do the following: `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.r set filetype=r`

Comment: Still no luck.  `filetype plugin on` doesn't seem to change anything either.